# Calling Jquery within / inside a Shadowbox

Tags: jquery, shadowbox

I have a simple Shadowbox that is called by jquery:

```
$('#statsButton').click(function() {
    thisContent = $('#userStats').html();
    Shadowbox.open({
        content: thisContent,
        player: "html"
    });
});
```

I have a div, in that `$('#userStats')` object that should alert on click:

```
$("#submitPosition").click(function(e) {
        alert('test');
});
```

But when I click, nothing happens.  Both of the above functions are wrapped in their own document ready blocks.  I call `Shadowbox.init` at the beginning of the script and it works great.  It's just that it ignores jQuery events inside.  Can anybody help?

Short recap:  Basically I have Shadowbox bring up and HTML player.  I want jQuery to act as expected within that HTML player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are loading content dynamically into a container, you should use jQuery `on()` to bind events to objects inside the content because using `click()` will only bind the event to the existing `#submitPosition`.

For instance:

```
$('body').on('click', '#submitPosition', function(e) {
   alert('test');
});
```

Also, using multiple elements on a page with the same id is not a good practice.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: There are not initially multiple elements with the same id, but once content from the #userStats div is loaded into the Shadowbox, there will be two instances of #submitPosition (in #userStats and Shadowbox). Just something to mind!

Comment: I changed this to the correct answer for two reasons: 1. live is deprecated and on is the correct jquery to use  2. the poster mentioned that the id is duplicated and this was very true (in fact, so true that when i tried to modify it through an ajax response, it failed.  anything inside the shadowbox should ALWAYS be a class)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#submitPosition").live('click',function(e) {
            alert('test');
    });
});
```

This will help.
Bcoz when this code intialise time the **#submitPosition** is not there in html.
But live will solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 options:

1) In your userStat div, change to:

```
$("#submitPosition").click(function(e) {
    alert('test');
}).click();
```

which will actually call your callback function.

2) Use the onOpen event of shadowbox:

```
$('#statsButton').click(function() {
    thisContent = $('#userStats').html();
    Shadowbox.open({
        content: thisContent,
        player: "html",
        onOpen: function(){ alert('test'); } 
    });
});
```